# List values from a range where it's value on another column is equal to "Done"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How do I get all values in Column A where it's value in Column B is equal to "Done" as a drop down value on another sheet?

Let's say on `Sheet 1`:

```
Column A  | Column B
Spongebob | In Progress
Patrick   | Done
Mr. Krabs | In Progress
Squidward | Done
Gary      | On Queue
```

Then on `Sheet 2, Column A`:

```
Column A
Patrick
Squidward
```

When doing the Data > Data Validation then select `List from a range` on the Criteria section, it just gets all the values from that column.

Comment: Are you asking how to create the `Sheet 2 Column A`? Or how to create a list from that already compiled `Sheet 2 Column A`?

Comment: How to create a list on `Sheet 2 Column A` wherein it will only get the values on `Sheet 1 Column A` whose values on `Column B` is equal to `Done`. In which in the given example above, Patrick and Squidward will only be the available values on the list on `Sheet 2 Column A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Sheet 2`, you can put this in `A1`, and drag down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5="Done",ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5))+1,""),ROW(Sheet1!A1)))
```

Note: It's an array formula, so enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

[image]

To hide errors, simply wrap `IFERROR()` around it:

```
=IFERROR([that formula],"")
```

Edit: Then, to create a list for a validated cell, create a Named Range where the results will be. I created the named range `data` for `Sheet2!A1:A20`, and you can use a drop down:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should I add this on the Data > Data Validation? On the Criteria field? This is because it seems not to work. :(

Comment: You'd use the above formula to create a named range [`Ctrl + F3`] and use the named range in data validation.

Comment: @basagabi That or assign data validation to done with an offset if that's possible.

Comment: @basagabi - See my edit. That does what you requested in your OP...I think.

Comment: Not a direct way and require additional steps along the way but it works!